# jQuery's width animation is hiding the overflow despite being visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm increasing the `width` of a `div` using jQuery's `.animate()`.

The `div` contains a child element which is absolutely positioned, with its boundaries crossing the parent's boundaries.

When the animation starts, the part of the child's `div` outside the parent element becomes invisible, when the animation is finished, it's visible again.

```
<div id=parent>
    <div id=child>
    </div>
</div>

#parent{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
#child{
    width:100px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
    top: 100px;
}

$("#parent").animate({width: '300'}, 2000);
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ue645/)**

Comment: remove negative value from right in your css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ue645/1/, use !important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery animate automatically forces the element to `overflow:hidden;` while it's animating.

You can fix this with an !important CSS Style:

```
#parent{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

---

**Edit**
Due to CSS precedence, inline styles may override `!important` styles. If so, try something like this

```
$("#parent").animate({width: '300'}, 2000).css('overflow', 'visible', 'important');
```

Comment: .css('overflow','visible','important')